# First RewriteRule gets skipped if I have a second one?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am turning crazy with this .htaccess:

I made this (and testing it out here https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/BBB

RewriteRule ^REMOVE(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/CCC [L]
```

The first rule should change `http://` to `https://` and add `/BBB` (which works on its own). The second rule should remove `/REMOVE` and add `/CCC`.

I give it the url `http://test-domain.com/REMOVE/AAA`

I expect the result to be `https://test-domain.com/AAA/BBB/CCC`

But instead it's just `https://test-domain.com/AAA/CCC`

As if the first RewriteRule was skipped, or as if the second rule was matching against the old url instead of the one resulting from the first rule. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, that is all the issue here . Your first rule redirects. Because the target is a full URL. That means the browser is redirected to the exact URL you specify. That second rule would get applied for https requests, but _only_ if that request contains a path starting with "REMOVE". Which the redirected URL does not.

Comment: After the first rule, I should be left with https://test-domain.com/REMOVE/AAA/BBB, shouldn't I? So I would still have the "REMOVE" left for the second rule to apply? According to what you say, my 2nd rule would be skipped, but the opposite happens here, it's my first rule that gets skipped.

Comment: No, wrong. 1. where should that "AAA" come from? And 2. the `/BBB` is certainly not matched by the pattern `^REMOVE`.

Comment: The `AAA` comes from the tested url: `http://test-domain.com/REMOVE/AAA`. `/BBB` isn't matched by `^REMOVE`, but by the second half of the regex: `(/.*)?` that you omitted here (the full regex being `^REMOVE(/.*)?$`). As mentioned, I already checked that the two rules DO work as intended separately, it's only when together that they don't chain the way I expect them to.

Comment: No. Sorry. 1. Your first rule explicitly rewrites to `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/BBB`. There is no aspect here which somehow adds something else. The `/AAA` from the test request is _not_ somehow captured and added to that URL. And 2. Your second rule _explicitly_ insists on "REMOVE" being the start of the string formed by the request URL path. Which does _not_ match `/BBB`.

Comment: So what I suggest is: your first rule should perform an external redirection from http to https: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]`. The, independent from that a second rule can internally rewrite the second incoming request as you like, maybe something like `RewriteRule ^/?REMOVE(/.*)?$ /BBB$1/CCC [END]`

Comment: I don't understand how the `/BBB` at the end of `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/BBB` get added to the end of the url? Especially when I specifically said that I tested it, and it does?? The `AAA` is captured by the `%{REQUEST_URI}` part. `REMOVE` is at the start of the matched string, RewriteRule matched against the URI, not the whole URL. I feel like I'm repeating myself, but I did check each rule individually, the first one alone results in `https://test-domain.com/REMOVE/AAA/BBB` and the second one alone results in `https://test-domain.com/AAA/CCC`

Comment: OK, all fine. Sorry that I tried to help ;-)